# Effecient way to enumerate bit vectors such that no two adjacent bits are set simultaneously

Tags: algorithm, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

How to efficiently enumerate bit vectors of length `N` such that no two adjacent bits are set simultaneously, ***using only bit operations (not recursion)***? You can assume `N <= 64`.

By "efficient", we mean the complexity is (much) smaller than `O(N * 2^N)`, because the naive way takes `O(N * 2^N)` (i.e. enumerating all of bit vectors and then removing those contradict the condition).

For example, when `N = 4`, I'd like to have

- `0000`
- `1000`
- `1010`
- etc.

but not

- `1100` (0th and 1st are both set)
- `0110` (1st and 2nd are both set)
- `1111` (all are set)
- etc.

[This Japanese book](https://book.mynavi.jp/ec/products/detail/id=22672) says there ***is*** such a way, but not explains about it at all, so I'm just posting this question.

Comment: I would try a recursive approach where in each recursion I branch for the 2 possibilities of the next bit (skipping the 1 branch if the previous bit already was a 1).

Comment: @MrSmith42 Thank you for your suggestion and I'm very sorry I forgot to write "using only bit operations (not recursion)" in OP. This is because the book says so and I'd like to avoid allocation if possible.

Comment: This sequence is https://oeis.org/A003714

Comment: @harold Thank you. This is exactly what I wanted. I just implemented it in Rust and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in [harold's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74784020/effecient-way-to-enumerate-bit-vectors-such-that-no-two-adjacent-bits-are-set-si/74784670#comment131983074_74784020), the sequence is known as *Fibbinary numbers* and [*OEIS A003714*](https://oeis.org/A003714) shows an efficient implementation.

I implemented and compared the following three methods:

- naive
- recursion (suggested in [MrSmith42's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74784020/effecient-way-to-enumerate-bit-vectors-such-that-no-two-adjacent-bits-are-set-si#comment131982465_74784020))
- efficient algorithm (shown in OEIS)

Performance:

```
n = 32

loop:      9.726627375s
recursion: 26.339083ms
efficient: 14.795916ms
```

Rust code ([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=07a84da054297789a0058ea6547e8763)):

```rust
//naive method
fn f1(n: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut mem = Vec::with_capacity(1 << n);
    'a: for i in 0..(1 << n) {
        for j in 1..n {
            if ((i & (1 << (j - 1)) != 0) && (i & (1 << j) != 0)) {
                continue 'a;
            }
        }
        mem.push(i);
    }
    mem
}

//recursive method
fn f2(cur: usize, i: usize, n: usize, mem: &mut Vec<usize>) {
    if (i == n) {
        mem.push(cur);
        return;
    }
    if (i == 0) {
        f2(cur, i + 1, n, mem);
        f2(cur | (1 << i), i + 1, n, mem);
    } else {
        f2(cur, i + 1, n, mem);
        if (cur & (1 << (i - 1)) == 0) {
            f2(cur | (1 << i), i + 1, n, mem);
        }
    }
}

//efficient method
//The sequence is known as `Fibbinary numbers`.
//ref: |https://oeis.org/A003714|
fn f3(n: usize) -> Vec<usize> {
    let mut mem = Vec::with_capacity(1 << n);
    let mut x = 0;
    loop {
        mem.push(x);
        let y = !(x >> 1);
        x = (x - y) & y;
        if ((1 << n) & x != 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    mem
}

use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let n = 32;

    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut mem1 = f1(n);
    println!("loop:      {:?}", start.elapsed());

    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut mem2 = Vec::with_capacity(1 << n);
    f2(0, 0, n, &mut mem2);
    println!("recursion: {:?}", start.elapsed());

    let start = Instant::now();
    let mut mem3 = f3(n);
    println!("efficient: {:?}", start.elapsed());

    mem1.sort();
    mem2.sort();
    mem3.sort();
    assert_eq!(mem1, mem2);
    assert_eq!(mem1, mem3);
}
```

Side note:

Given an integer `x`, one can know if `x` is a Fibbinary number by `(x << 1) & x == 0` (proof: trivial by the definition of Fibbinary numbers).

Answer (score 0):

Start with 1.

On each iteration, take all binary numbers of length k and append '0' and '01' to the end of each (separately), turning each into two new bitvectors of length k+1 and k+2.

Repeat until you have all bitvecs up to the length you want.

Ruby code:

```
def get_bitvecs(max_len)
  ans = []
  
  unprocessed_bitvecs = [[], ['1']]
  parity = 1
  
  loop do 
    cur_bv = unprocessed_bitvecs[parity].shift # take first element from array
    cur_len = cur_bv.length
    unprocessed_bitvecs[(parity + 1) % 2].append(cur_bv + '0')
    unprocessed_bitvecs[parity].append(cur_bv + '01')
    ans.append(cur_bv)
    if unprocessed_bitvecs[parity][0].length > cur_len
      return ans if cur_len >= max_len
      parity = (parity + 1) % 2
    end  
  end
end
```

Output of code:

```
> get_bitvecs(7)
=> 
["1",
 "10",
 "101",
 "100",
 "1001",
 "1010",
 "1000",
 "10101",
 "10001",
 "10010",
 "10100",
 "10000",
 "100101",
 "101001",
 "100001",
 "101010",
 "100010",
 "100100",
 "101000",
 "100000",
 "1010101",
 "1000101",
 "1001001",
 "1010001",
 "1000001",
 "1001010",
 "1010010",
 "1000010",
 "1010100",
 "1000100",
 "1001000",
 "1010000",
 "1000000"]
```

Comment: This produces strings; if you prefer, you could use integers by shifting 1 instead of appending '0', and shifting 2, then |= 1 instead of appending '01'. E.g., from one we get 1 << 1 = 2 = "10" and 1 << 2 | 1 = "101"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these bit vectors are generated consecutively as integers, they form the sequence [oeis.org/A003714](https://oeis.org/A003714) as pointed out by [harold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555045/harold) in comments. A trivial way to generate this sequence is to simply iterate through the integers in ascending order and eliminate all that have two adjacent bits in their binary representation.

For this, we can modify the null-byte detecting technique invented by Alan Mycroft in 1987, modified to find bit-pairs (instead of bytes) that are zero. Two adjacent 1-bits form a bit pair with value 3, so we need to XOR with the integer in which all bit- pairs have value 3 prior to applying Mycroft's "magic". Mycroft's detection works on *naturally aligned* bit groups. To find bit pairs with value 3 starting at odd bit indexes, we need to also examine the original value shifted right by 1.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

/*
 Derived from Alan Mycroft's null-byte detection, posted to comp.lang.c on April 9, 1987.
 Original at: https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.c/c/2HtQXvg7iKc/m/xOJeipH6KLMJ
*/
#define aligned_bitpair_zero(x) ((x - 0x55555555) & (~x & 0xaaaaaaaa))

int main (void)
{
    for (uint32_t x = 0; x <= 264; x++) {
        uint32_t s = x ^ 0xffffffff;            // looking for bit-pairs with value 3
        uint32_t sf = aligned_bitpair_zero (s); // examine bit-pairs at even bit indexes
        uint32_t t = s >> 1;                   
        uint32_t tf = aligned_bitpair_zero (t); // examine bit-pairs at odd bit indexes
        if ((sf | tf) == 0) printf ("%u, ", x);
    };
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The output of the above program should be:

```
0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18, 20, 21, 32, 33, 34, 36, 37, 40, 41, 42, 64, 65, 66, 68, 69, 72, 73, 74, 80, 81, 82, 84, 85, 128, 129, 130, 132, 133, 136, 137, 138, 144, 145, 146, 148, 149, 160, 161, 162, 164, 165, 168, 169, 170, 256, 257, 258, 260, 261, 264,
```

On further reflection, my initial thoughts were overly complicated. One can easily detect whether there are consecutive 1-bits by ANDing the even-indexed bits with the odd-indexed bits. A non-zero result indicates that there were at least two adjacent 1-bits.

```c
int main (void)
{
    for (uint32_t x = 0; x <= 264; x++) {
        if (((x >> 1) & x) == 0) printf ("%u, ", x);
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```